# pass single value instead of list django

Tags: python, html, django

In django `list_of_ids = request.POST.getlist('field_name')` is used to get values from all the html fields with name `field_name` which returns list type object, even if only one field exists with the name `field_name`.

So if only one field exists with the given field name how to pass it as a single object of char or int type instead of list_type?

e.g.

```
<form action="{% url 'pack' %}">
    <button type="submit">
    <input type="text" name="tid">
</form>
```

In django views.py file:

```
def method_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        list_of_ids = request.POST.getlist('field_name')
```

what i want is like

```
list_of_ids = request.POST.getobject('field_name')
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`request.POST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) is a dict-like object, it [implements `__getitem__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.__getitem__) so you only need to use `request.POST['field_name']` to retrieve the value for that field.

Additionally if you want to provide a default value in case a the key is not present you can use [`request.POST.get`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.get) i.e. `request.POST.get('field_name', 'default-text')`